# log Redis commands fired by Redisson Java client

Tags: java, redis, redisson

Is there any available logger that can be used to show the commands executed by Redisson to Redis?
e.g. like *hibernate show sql flag*.

Something like when code does `redisson.getJsonBucket().set()` then the respective redis command `JSON.SET` is logged.

Thanks.